# Controlling Inner and Outer Borders via CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table and would like to control inner and outer borders of this style: border: 3px double #000000

What would the css be to do inner and outer borders, I think that by using

```
.border {
 border-bottom: 3px double #000000
 border-top: 3px double #000000
 border-left: 3px double #000000
 border-right: 3px double #000000

}
```

is a bit much per td cell, there has to be a different way, and probably better.

Comment: Could you please put an example setup on http://www.jsfiddle.net ? That would make it much easier for us to understand what you mean exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not understanding what do you mean by inner, outer borders? do you want table and td borders to be different? if its that so try this

```
table {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #00ff00;
}
```

If you want the same border for entire `table` including `td`, somewhat like `border="1"` than try this

```
table, td {
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change .border to .td and it should work fine